# How do we resolve network service to get addresses and port in Swift using NetBrowserService

Tags: swift

I am having issues with getting the ip (addresses) dictionary and port number for network service. When the code runs the only thing I get is the service name. addresses returns a empty array and port returns -1

```
import Foundation
import Network

class SocketIoManager: NSObject, NetServiceBrowserDelegate, NetServiceDelegate {
   
    private var browser: NetServiceBrowser!

    private  override init() {
        super.init()
        browser = NetServiceBrowser()
        browser.delegate = self
        browser.searchForServices(ofType: "_itworks._tcp", inDomain: "")
    
    }
    
    func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didFind service: NetService, moreComing: Bool) {
            let serviceInfo = self.serializeService(toDictionary: service, resolved: false)
            print(serviceInfo)
    }
    
    
    private func serializeService(toDictionary service: NetService, resolved: Bool) -> [String: Any] {
        var serviceInfo: [String: Any] = [:]
        serviceInfo["name"] = service.name
        serviceInfo["host"] = service.hostName
        serviceInfo["port"] = service.port
        serviceInfo["addresses"] = addressesFromService(service)
        return serviceInfo
    }
    
    func addressesFromService(_ service: NetService) -> [String] {
        var addresses = [String]()

     
        var addressBuffer = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))

        for data in service.addresses ?? [] {
            memset(&addressBuffer, 0, Int(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))

            typealias IPSocketAddress = (
                sa: sockaddr,
                ipv4: sockaddr_in,
                ipv6: sockaddr_in6
            )

            var socketAddress = data.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<IPSocketAddress>) -> IPSocketAddress in
                return pointer.pointee
            }

            if socketAddress.sa.sa_family == sa_family_t(AF_INET) || socketAddress.sa.sa_family == sa_family_t(AF_INET6) {
                let addressStr = socketAddress.sa.sa_family == sa_family_t(AF_INET)
                    ? inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(socketAddress.ipv4.sin_addr), &addressBuffer, socklen_t(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))
                    : inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(socketAddress.ipv6.sin6_addr), &addressBuffer, socklen_t(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN))

                if let addressStr = addressStr, let address = String(utf8String: addressStr) {
                    addresses.append(address)
                }
            }
        }

        return addresses
    }
```

Basically when the code runs I get the following that prints to console
["name": "itworks", "port": -1, "addresses": []]

Comment: You could try using: `service.resolve(withTimeout: 10.0)`
     before using it in your `serializeService(...)`.

Comment: Just gave it a try but sill only get the following ```["name": "itworks", "port": -1, "addresses": []]```